# While connecting metamask not able to transfer funds to another account

Tags: web3js, metamask, cosmos

I have setup and run a node locally in my system by using these commands

```
"./evmosd init test --chain-id=evmos_9000-6
./evmosd keys add t1
./evmosd add-genesis-account t1 1000000000000000000000000aevmos,1000000000000000000000000000stake
./evmosd gentx t1 1000000000000000000stake
./evmosd collect-gentxs
./evmosd validate-genesis
./evmosd start"
```

and able to add funds on evmos account. When I import that account on metamask through its private key, It added successfully and funds also shown there. But When I transfer the funds from one account to another through metamask it gives me an error like this:

[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"code":-32000,"message":"tx gas (125677) exceeds block gas limit (0): out of gas: out of gas"}}}'

[Metamask Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2i3T.png)

Same error face on while deploying the contract with remix IDE. See the screenshot.

[image: Contract Error]

[image: Evmos Metamask Funds]

While connecting metamask not able to transfer funds to another account

I have tried these methods:

- When I send evmos tokens through terminal it successfully sent to another account.
- If I send through metamask or Web3 js library its gives me this error

"[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"code":-32000,"message":"tx gas (125677) exceeds block gas limit (0): out of gas: out of gas"}}}'"

I have enough faucets to transfer as you can see on above screenshot. I have used EVMOS v11.0.0

Answer (score 0):

after init chain,modify genesis file (data/config/genesis.json) set  consensus_params->block->max_gas to an positive number(e.g. 10000000). then start your chain.